# C# Progress Bar that will update when button that runs macros is clicked

Tags: c#, winforms

So I have a button that will run macros when clicked in my code, I want my progress bar to update when each macro finishes running, so my progress bar will be complete when the last macro runs. How do I link this a progress bar to this button click event instead of using a timer and increments?

```
private void createAllButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ReportscheckBox.Checked == true)
            {
                Operation.RunMacro("ExportReports.cs");
            }
            
            if (CNCcheckBox.Checked == true)
            {
                Operation.RunMacro("ExportNC.cs");
            }
            if (DrawingscheckBox.Checked == true)
            {
                Operation.RunMacro("ExportShaft2.cs");
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                Operation.RunMacro("ExportPlate.cs");
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                Operation.RunMacro("ExportAssembly.cs");
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
            if (GAcheckBox.Checked == true)
            {
                Operation.RunMacro("ExportPDF2.cs");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Operation.RunMacro("ExportIFC.cs");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Operation.RunMacro("ExportDWG.cs");
            }
            packageButton.Show();
        }
```

This is the button click event code that I want to link the progress bar too, the tricky thing is I wont have the same macros running every time.

Comment: Could you add some more information about what `Operation.RunMacro();` is doing? Is it running jobs in parallel?

Comment: Your code wait until `Operation.RunMacro` complete or runs it and go to next without waiting for complete? How you can determine completion?

Comment: its exporting files from a different application

Comment: Does it WAITS to complete by itself?

Comment: each macro only takes 10-15 seconds and they run one at a time in order of the code, not all at once

Comment: Thread.Sleep in an Event Handler is really a no-no ... but on topic: what have you tried? Does `Operation.RunMacro` block until the macro finishes?

Comment: Then at the start of the button click work out which boxes are ticked (hence which tasks will run). Estimate the relative time for each task, then after each `.RunMacro()` you can update a progress bar with the approximate progress.

Comment: this.btnprogress.increment(1); after each macro runs, but wont work if i change what macros will run

Comment: time estimate will be my best bet probably but sometimes the macros will take a little longer than usual

Comment: Do you want the progress bar to represent a "time" progress or a "tasks" progress. If you cannot reasonably estimate runtime, you my just show "1 of 5 tasks" ... How many Macros will run you will have to count upfront, of course.

Comment: Btw.: I'd probably run the macros on a different thread, so the progressbar actually has a chance to get updated ...

Comment: Unfortunately progress bars are really hard to get accurate if they depend on anything external or non-deterministic (thing file transfer progress). You might be better displaying something like:
Currently running macro x - x of N

Comment: As @Fildor stated, it is a good idea (tbf a necessesity) to move these calls to a separate thread because your window will be unresponsive during 5 seconds sleeps, which may cause application not responding warnings to the user (window going pale).

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of macro which needed to be executed.
In `if` conditions replace macro run with adding to list.
Then iterate the list and run each macro.

Progress can be updated in two ways:

1. Set List of macros to run count as `ProgressBar.MaxValue`.
   On each loop iteration set number of iteration as current `ProgressBar.Value`.
2. Calculate percentage base on current iteration and total macros to run.
   Do not change `ProgressBar.MaxValue` in this option, just set percentage as `ProgressBar.Value`.

See example below:

```
private void createAllButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create a list to storep all macro which needed to be executed
    List<string> macrosToRun = new List<string>();

    if (ReportscheckBox.Checked == true)
    {
        macrosToRun.Add("ExportReports.cs");
    }

    if (CNCcheckBox.Checked == true)
    {
        macrosToRun.Add("ExportNC.cs");
    }

    if (DrawingscheckBox.Checked == true)
    {
        macrosToRun.Add("ExportShaft2.cs");
        macrosToRun.Add("ExportPlate.cs");
        macrosToRun.Add("ExportAssembly.cs");
    }

    if (GAcheckBox.Checked == true)
    {
        macrosToRun.Add("ExportPDF2.cs");
        macrosToRun.Add("ExportIFC.cs");
        macrosToRun.Add("ExportDWG.cs");
    }

    // Set ProgressBar.MaxValue as total macros stored in list:
    // yourProgressBar.MaxValue = macrosToRun.Count;

    // Run each macro through the loop
    for (int i = 0; i < macrosToRun.Count; i++)
    {
        string macro = macrosToRun[i];
        Operation.RunMacro(macro);

        // Update progress by loop iteration.
        // yourProgressBar.Value = i;

        // Another way - to not set ProgressBar.MaxValue
        // and calculate percentage:
        // int progressPercentage = (int)Math.Round(i * 100D / macrosToRun.Count);
        // yourProgressBar.Value = progressPercentage;
        
    }

    packageButton.Show();
}
```